# How do real schedulers involved processes and threads work?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, context-switch

I know the thread context switching is more lightweight than process context switching.
Because of

- There is less context of threads to store/load than processes.
- Caches work better.

So, I think it would have to switch threads of a process continuously, just like A1->A2->A1->B1->B2->B3->..., where 'A' and 'B' represent two different processes and the followed numbers represent the different thread of a process.

Unfortunately, I've never found any description about context switching to verify my thought. they all just told me the difference between thread and process.

Could you give me an example about how the scheduler switches different processes and their threads?

Comment: *"know the thread context switching is more lightweight than process context switching"* Modern operating systems do not schedule processes but threads. All processes have at least one (main) thread. Besides, OS tends to schedule *tasks* and not even threads or processes though tasks are generally threads. This is the case for Linux (on Windows the implementation is close-source but details about the behaviour are publicly available). Switching from one thread of a process A to a thread of a process B is more expensive because of things like TLB flushing (sometimes even the whole L1 cache).

Comment: Regarding Linux, note that the sources of the scheduler are available (even from the web). The sources are not so difficult to read (even for beginners I think). AFAIR, the task structure contains informations about the related thread & process. If you want a non-specific OS answer, then you should read books. In this case, IMHO the question is not a programming question anymore but a more general computer science one.